In PostgreSQL how to build polygons using lines around each dot
Probably a bit hard to explain but hopefully the image can explain better
There are 2 datasets, one is a point, the other is a line. Intended outcome is having polygons based on them
The lines form a shape around each point which I need to build a polygon out of, which I've highlighted as the shaded areas in yellow. But there can be multiple lines that can form each polygon, which I gave 2 examples in orange:


Polygonize all lines then inner join your points to them, and select distinct polygons:
with polygonized as (
select l.id, st_makepolygon((st_dump(l.geom)).geom) as geom
from test.lines as l
)
select distinct on (polygonized.id) polygonized.* from polygonized
join test.points_in_lines as p
on st_intersects(polygonized.geom, p.geom)



I needed to use ST_NumPoints(part_geom) >= 4 and
ST_IsClosed(part_geom) otherwise it wouldn't work. But somehow it didnt work in many cases like in the below  https://i.sstatic.net/QsN9WFIn.png

The polygon in your screenshot is self intersecting = invalid

Is there anyway to maybe make it at least a little bit tolerant of bad geometries? maybe like a buffer?
